# Custom Django Form - modify cleaned data based on request

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

This has most likely already been asked before, but I could not figure out the right thing to google. I am creating a simple form for people to fill out a COVID screen for an event. Basically, they click on an event and then click fill out form.

I have created a model for this as such:

```py
class Response(models.Model):
    """ model for a completed covid screen """

    temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=98.6)
    contact_with_covid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    event = models.ForeignKey("Event", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.account.user.username}\'s response for "{self.event.title}"'
```

As well as created a form for users to fill out for this response.

```py
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ['temperature', 'contact_with_covid']
        labels = {'contact_with_covid': 'Have you had contact with covid in the last 14 days?'}
        help_texts = {'temperature': 'Your temperature in degrees.'}
```

I did not want the user to select the `account`, `time` and `event` parameters. They should be defined as such:

- account should be the currently logged in user

  - `request.user.account`
- time should be the time of submission

  - `datetime.datetime.now()`
- event should be the event in the URL parameter.

  - `path('event/<uuid:event>/response/create', views.create_response, name='response-create')`

Therefore, the view I have sets these parameters in `cleaned_data` after the form is validated.

```py
@login_required
def create_response(request, event):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['account'] = request.user.account
            form.cleaned_data['event'] = event
            form.cleaned_data['time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your response has been recorded')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ResponseForm()
    return render(request, 'prescreen/response_form.html', {'form': form})
```

However, whenever I submit the form I get a screen "NOT NULL constraint failed: prescreen_response.time".
[image]

How is this possible when I have set the `time` parameter of `cleaned_data`?

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is in your form, try to do it like this:

```
@login_required
def create_response(request, event):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(commit=False)
            account = request.user.account
            event = form.cleaned_data['event']
            time = datetime.datetime.now()
            response.account = account
            response.event = event
            response.time = time
            response.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your response has been recorded')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ResponseForm()
    return render(request, 'prescreen/response_form.html', {'form': form})
```

the problem could also be in how you defined your DateTime field in the model, try to do it like this: `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and then skip the time part in the form entirely

Comment: When in django... use `django.utils.timezone`, not datetime. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) or as SLDem mentioned at the end of his post, define your model with `auto_now_add=True`.

Edit: This should have been a comment on posters question. But alas, now it is here. Let's roll with it.